# Intellij: Run button disabled for tcServer

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and trying to get my web application to launch using tcServer

I am using a local configuration, and have added a run configuration. See attached screenshots

However, when I attempt to run this, the Run button is disabled.

What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have edited a default configuration, you did not add a new runnable server configuration. In order to do that click on the **green + sign** at the top left of the run screen.

You should remove the war from the default configuration and add it in the newly created server.

see attached, screenshot, you can see the difference between a default and a runnable configuration

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have to use the little green "+" in the upper left corner. The one you edited is just the default setting for your spring server. If you add a specific run configuration like that to your project it will appear. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck there for hours. 
Why did someone put a disabled run button on a template which is not something that can be actually run?